# How to hide/show the icon button from the application bar in windows phone 8 apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am developing an application for windows phone 8. My problem is I could't hide/show an icon button from the application bar. Any one tell me the answer if you have.

Comment: is this what you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234202/hide-application-bar-icon-programmatically-in-a-wp7-silverlight-application

Comment: share your code. let me try

Comment: @RIPS10- No, Am looking for the solution to hide/show not enable/disable the control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can't access direclty the visibilty propety of application bar,and so other way is remove icon when u no need it and add it again when you need it.

To Remove first appicon,

```
ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(0);
```

To Add,

```
ApplicationBarIconButton b = new ApplicationBarIconButton();
b.Text = i.ToString();
b.IconUri = new Uri("/Images/icon1.png", UriKind.Relative);
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either hide the whole application bar:

`ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false`

when you want to hide the appbar. Set it to true whenever you want to display it.

Else you can hide individual buttons by:

`((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[buttonIndex]).IsEnabled = false;`

Hope it helps.

Comment: there is a difference between hiding and disabling something

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear about your question, which one you need. So I share you some options about applicationBar & Menu which I know.

- Completely hide appBar from your application page.

  1. C#

     ```
     ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;
     ```
  2. XAML

     ```
     <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible = false; />
     ```
- If want to minimized applicationBar

  ```
  ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Minimized;  // to minimize
  ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;    //to get normal view
  ```
- For disable

  ```
  ApplicationBarIconButton _timerAppBarIconBtn;
  _timerAppBarIconBtn.IsEnabled = false;
  ```
- Competely remove ApplicationBar & MenuItems

  ```
      for (int i = ApplicationBar.Buttons.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(i);

      for (int i = ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
          ApplicationBar.MenuItems.RemoveAt(i);
  ```
- Add ApplicationBar

  ```
  ApplicationBarIconButton _timerAppBarIconBtn;
  _timerAppBarIconBtn = new ApplicationBarIconButton
  {
      IconUri = new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/timer.png", UriKind.Relative),
      Text = "timer"
   };
   _timerAppBarIconBtn.Click += (s, v) => MaintainTimer(); //call a method
   ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(_rotateAppBarIconBtn);
  ```