# Hide AppBarButton using visibility collapsed

Tags: c#, xaml

I have an app that check if users are admins or not, and if not I want to hide some commands, like AppBarButton and menuflyout. How do I hide those commands using visibility.collapsed in the code behind when the user is not an admin?

```
private async void Button_OK(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Utilizador u = new Utilizador(null, TextBox1.Text, PasswordBox1.Password, null, null, false);
    if (u.GetByLoginAndPassword())
    {
        if (UtilizadorViewModel.Utilizador.Admin == false)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), UtilizadorViewModel.Utilizador.Nome);
            //Visibility.Collapsed;
            MessageDialog a = new MessageDialog("Bem Vindo! ", u.Nome);
            await a.ShowAsync();
        } else
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1), UtilizadorViewModel.Utilizador.Nome);
            //Visibility.Visible;
            MessageDialog a = new MessageDialog("Bem Vindo! ", u.Nome);
            await a.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Nome ou password errados");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="addp" Label="Add" Tapped="AppBarButton_Tapped" Icon="Add"/>
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the entire application bar or set it's visibility to collapsed:

- `ApplicationBar.IsVisible = false;`
- `ApplicationBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;`

If you need to access individual buttons, you could use 2 approaches,
   you can either completely remove the button:

- `ApplicationBar.Buttons.RemoveAt(0);`

or use that button's index and set it's `IsEnabled` property:

- `((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[buttonIndex]).IsEnabled = false;`

[If you need additional information - this answer explains it very well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234202/hide-application-bar-icon-programmatically-in-a-wp7-silverlight-application)

[Check out this one too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605324/how-to-hide-show-the-icon-button-from-the-application-bar-in-windows-phone-8-app)